# How to check if value HAS NO punctuation or numbers with RegEx using JS

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm validating an email form and for the name input I wanna make sure the user didn't enter in punctuation, or numbers in the field.  Just letters a-z upper-cased, and lower-cased.

This doesn't seem to work:

```
/(?![\._])\p{P}|[0-9]/g
```

Comment: What do you have against `José O'Brien`?

Comment: What are you talking about?  Like I wanna keep the accent marks, too.

Comment: allow only A-Za-z instead to all this stuff.

Comment: `O'Brien` contains punctuation. Don't try to validate names: [Falsehoods programmers believe about names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: @TimPietzcker I'm 99% sure that he would be Jose.obrian@whatever.com or jobrian - not many systems allow non low-ASCII and accents in email addresses

Comment: @mplungjan: He's not validating an email field but a name field. Otherwise, he would probably want to allow the `@` and dots, don't you think?

Comment: This is the correct email one:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript

Comment: Oh dear. This is getting worse. Where did you find this nonsensical monster? This will reject many valid mail addresses and fail to reject many invalid ones. Why bother? Check if there is an `@` in the field, then try and send mail to it and catch any errors.

Comment: @TimPietzcker is this correct? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript

Comment: The second answer is: http://stackoverflow.com/a/815232/20670

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just match on `/[a-zA-Z]/g` then?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use

```
/[a-zA-Z]/g
```

To match a valid name

Hope this helps

Comment: This is incorrect. It matches as soon as there is a single ASCII letter. And it uses the global modifier for no discernible purpose.

Comment: You are welcome, if you like you may flag this answer as correct? Thx

Comment: Tim the regex is applied to a single string so it is correct to match the first letter and the global scope

Comment: Sorry, cannot flag.  I have 1 rep only.